# Vuejs why all the methods are called?

Tags: vue.js, vue-directives

In the following code first tag `p` renders `name` and it is also binded to input event of input field.
There is method called random and it generates random number. And it is rendered in the last `p` tag. Wondering why `random` `method` is being called for every character `input` in the `input` box? Shouldn't that be executed only one?

I know I can add Vuejs directive `v-once` to the last `p` tag and it stays the same.

Can anyone help me understand this better?

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.productionTip = false
new Vue({
el:"#exercise",
data: {
    name: "Tokyo",
},
methods: {
    changeName: function(event){
        this.name = event.target.value;
    },
    random: function(){
        return Math.random();
    }
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="exercise">
    <p>VueJS is pretty cool - {{ name }}</p>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" v-bind:value="name" v-on:input="changeName">
    <br/>
    <p>{{random()}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It updateds because its binded to your vue instance. Whenever `name` changes it will automatically change in the DOM.

With every key press you trigger the method `changeName`. Now `changeName` changes `name`. Vue.js detect this change and update your DOM.

Comment: I understand now! can't I say don't update the whole DOM but to update only the required?

Comment: it only updates the data that changed in your case its only `name`

Comment: @Ifaruki I think the OP was referring to why the random number updates when `name` is changed, the random number is not linked to `name`, apart from that it's in the same template.